# Storm 1.1.0 Multi Node Cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

I am using Storm v1.1.0, and I am building Storm on different machines, lets say I have 5 machines,

- machine1: Zookeeper
- machine2: Nimbus
- machine3: Supervisor1
- machine4: Supervisor2
- machine5: UI

And the configuration of each machine is the following:

```
machine1 
    tickTime=2000
    initLimit=10
    syncLimit=5
    dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
    clientPort=2181

machine2
    storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
    storm.zookeeper.servers: - "ZookeeperIP"

machines(3-4)
    storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
    storm.zookeeper.servers: 
     - "ZookeeperIP"
    nimbus.seeds: ["NimbusIP"]

machine5
    storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
    storm.zookeeper.servers: 
     - "ZookeeperIP"
    nimbus.seeds: ["NimbusIP"]
    ui.port: 8080
```

All is running okay no errors, and I also checked logs, but no errors also all of them are running and starting fine!

The problem is [UI is showing anything and gives error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EeA9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
machine5
    storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
    storm.zookeeper.servers: 
     - "ZookeeperIP"
    nimbus.seeds: ["NimbusIP"]
    ui.port: 8080
```

This configuration should be available in machine 2-5. From your description, 
**machine 2** is missing **nimbus.seeds** and **ui.port**. **Machine 3-4** is missing **ui.port**.

Try keeping the same configuration throughout your storm cluster.